# How to convert invalid object format to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a string in this format:

> {"FactoreId":1"FactoreItems":c, d, b, a}

How can I convert this string to JSON?

Comment: Do you mean simply turning this into a json formatted string i.e. `JSON.stringify( '{"FactoreId":1"FactoreItems":c, d, b, a}' )`?

Comment: @hitautodestruct It won't work, since it is not a valid JSON string.

Comment: @GuillaumePoussel Notice the `.stringify` method. I'm not asking if he wants to parse it into JS I'm asking if he wants to encode it into a string.. (throw the code into your console to see what I mean)

Comment: @hitautodestruct : yeah, JSON = javascript object notation. The name itself suggests that json is a valid js object. The one here cannot even be called a collection of key,value pairs

Comment: @ArunAravind Yeah I know what a JSON object looks like. I was simply asking if maybe he wanted to turn the string into a JSON string: `"{\"FactoreId\":1\"FactoreItems\":c, d, b, a}"`. Which doesn't really make sense, but maybe he does not know that.

Comment: i know that this format not correct for JSON, but i need this format for use in other place, how can convert this to JSON?

Comment: How did you get such string? Because it wasn't serialized the right way, like using a json serializer. It seems like was concatenated string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are "d, b, a" part of FactoreItems ? If so:

```
{"FactoreId":1, "FactoreItems":["c", "d", "b", "a"]}
```

In case c, d, b and a are variables, then remove double quotes from the example above.

Once your string is in the correct format, you may use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert it to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid json.
JSON = 'JavaScript Object Notation'. 
The string which you are presenting cannot be a valid js object.

Visit http://www.json.org/

They have put up the whole grammar for json.

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: Had an issue with the comment. Thats why. sorry about that. I have commented it now below the question